# how to profile a Haskell programm with lots of System.Process.readProcess?

Tags: haskell, profiling

I have a multi-threaded Haskell program that calls an external program with `System.Process.readProcess`, and does this very often. How can I measure performance? (to decide whether I should improve my program, or the external one.) How does the "external time" show up in the profile (+RTS -p), or in the eventlog (the threadscope picture)?

Comment: Do it with snapshots of the stack. Take 10 of them. If, for example, it is in `readProcess` on 6 of them, that means the external program is taking 60% of that thread's time, roughly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ProcMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) for this task.

Put filters on your processes name, select only 'Show processes and thread activity' and you can see exactly which is more time consuming. You can even save and parse the log for a long time monitoring.

I also suggest you to use another approach to this problem:

1. Child process

   1. Create a loop over main and wait for an external event (socket, pipe, etc.)
   2. Process the request and send the result
   3. Block until the next request.
2. Main process:

   1. Spawn one or more child process
   2. Send the request to an available child
   3. Wait for response

This way you get rid of the overhead wasted in continuously spawn / kill of child process.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Criterion](http://www.serpentine.com/criterion/), a Haskell microbenchmarking library?

> This library provides a powerful but simple way to measure software performance. It provides both a framework for executing and analysing benchmarks and a set of driver functions that makes it easy to build and run benchmarks, and to analyse their results.